# What would be a good bike for urban commute? (3-4km)

Tags: commuter, commuting-bike, urban-riding

I have been riding bicycles for quite a long time now, but have never done it on city roads. Instead, I have been riding **a rented bike** in a park which has specific bike lanes (the same size as the car lane) and doing laps (it has sealed roads).

Now I want ride for my commute, but have no experience riding on roads with other cars.

I'm going to be buying a bicycle, but have no idea where to start looking. Here are my ideal features / requirements:

- Somewhere below $600 USD (but the cheaper the better)
- Good for riding on city roads and in traffic
- My commute would be about 3-4km, I don't know if that changes anything
- Safe
- Fairly good for riding up hills (I live in quite a hilly area)
- Hopefully still fun to ride

**Is anybody able to give me some recommendations, pointers in the right direction or specific types / features to look into?**

One time I was at somewhere hiring a bike and I really liked it, I'm fairly sure that it was an [Avanti Giro F1](http://www.avantibikes.com/au/bikes/road-bikes/sport-road-bike/giro-f-1-road-bike/), so possibly something similar?

Thanks and sorry for my newbie question, hopefully it isn't too broad ;P

P.S. I'm male

Comment: At that distance, any style of bike will do.  You need reliable and comfortable.  Since you're buying new, finding a comfortable-to-you bike is the goal.  Go to a LBS and try out some commuter bikes, which are flat-bar MTBs but with no suspension, so rigid forks.  Mudguards/fenders and maybe a pannier rack for your stuff.  We don't make brand recommendations.

Comment: Yep, pretty much any bike.  I'd recommend used.  You don't want something excessively heavy, and with hills you should probably have a multispeed bike.  If you liked that Avanti then something like that should be fine.  Note that that's not a super-fancy bike, so finding an equivalent should not be difficult, even if you don't get the exact same thing.  *Just make sure you test ride it before you buy.*

Comment: Don't discount the cost saving of a used bike either - If you find commuting isn't your thing then keep the bike for rides at the park to save on rental.

Comment: This is being closed as Off Topic because its aimed at brands.  SE is trying to build useful answers for the long term, so recommending a model is only relevant while its available, plus there will be regional dependency as well.     If the question was more like "What features should one look for on a commuter bike?" then that would still be useful in a decade.